# How can I make this kind button using css

Tags: css

I want to make a fancy button (The button Example image is attached below), I actually Saw this button on a [website](https://www.tiny.cloud/)

I am a beginner to CSS, I have very less idea about it but still I want to know how we can make buttons like this, along with it's hover effect, Please help me out...

The image of the button :-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Exrf9.png)

Comment: You can use pseudo class to do that

Comment: press `F12` and use inspect element to figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

You can check the button snippet below created using pseudo class.

I used `position: absolute` to arrange the border. You can align it anywhere using the `top` and `left` properties.

```css
button {
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #335dff;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

button::after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #335dff;
  position: absolute;
  height: 35px;
  left: -5px;
  top: 5px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

section {
  background-color: #000;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <button>Click</button>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code they use as @MMD suggests you can see that there are two main things in use.

Each link has a before pseudo element with a left and bottom border positioned absolutely relative to the a element and the border color is picked up from a CSS variable --bg.

To get the hover effect note that on hover the button tranlates down and left while the amount the pseudo element is offset from the button reduces to zero.

```html
<style>
  body {
    background: black;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
  }
  
  .link {
    width: 20vmin;
    height: 10vmin;
    padding: 2vmin;
    background-color: var(--bg);
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 2vmin;
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    transition: transform 0.3s linear;
  }
  
  .link::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 1vmin;
    left: -1vmin;
    border: solid var(--bg) 1px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  
  .link:hover {
    transform: translate(-1vmin, 1vmin);
  }
  
  .link:hover::before {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
  
  .link1 {
    --bg: white;
  }
  
  .link2 {
    --bg: cyan;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <a class="link link1">Link1</a>
  <a class="link link2">Link2</a>
</body>
```